# How would i convert This packet

Tags: perl, packet

How do i change this:

```
$sIPAddr = "37.221.175.211";                                                         
$iPort = 7777;                                                                  
$sPacket = "";                                                                 
$aIPAddr = explode('.', $sIPAddr);                                              

$sPacket .= "SAMP";                                                            

$sPacket .= chr($aIPAddr[0]);                                                   
$sPacket .= chr($aIPAddr[1]);                                                   
$sPacket .= chr($aIPAddr[2]);                                                   
$sPacket .= chr($aIPAddr[3]);                                                  

$sPacket .= chr($iPort & 0xFF);                                                 
$sPacket .= chr($iPort >> 8 & 0xFF);                                        

$sPacket .= 'c';
```

into this format:

```
"\x30\x23\x02\x01\x01\x04\x06\x70\x75\x62\x6c\x69\x63\xa5\x16\x02\x02\x4e\x47"
```

i dont even know what they are called.

Comment: 1) It's not clear what your question is.  2) 'explode' is a php function, not perl -- are you sure this is perl code?

Comment: You appear to be attempting to construct an SA:MP query, but if that is the case, your expected outcome doesn't look correct at all.  For one thing, the first four bytes should be the "SAMP" string.  (I have never heard of this before, but found http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism by googling for "SAMP" and "packet".)

Comment: ... Indeed, scrolling down the page a bit, the code sample is a copy/paste from there, and the language is indeed PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really have no idea what you did to get these Numbers. There is a string inside *`public`*.

To convert normal dec. numbers to hex, you can use `sprintf` or `printf` with `%x`. For example:

```
my $sIPAddr = "37.221.175.211";
my $iPort   = 7777;
my @aIPAddr = split /\./, $sIPAddr;
print map {sprintf '\0x%x',$_ } @aIPAddr;
```

Output:

```
\0x25\0xdd\0xaf\0xd3
```

Comment: And the port number 7777 is hex \x1e\x61.  But none of these things seem to be present in the expected outcome.

Comment: yeah. I really dont get the point :P.